# Why I cannot set T-SQL CONTXT_INFO variable in one line statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to set `CONTEXT_INFO` variable in SQL Server to user session unique identifier, GUID of user's session to be exact.

But I cannot perform this operation in more or less short and clean one-liner. I'm obligatory to create new binary variable and only than assign it to the `CONTEXT_INFO`.

It looks like this:

```
DECLARE @sessionId binary(16) = CAST(CAST('A53BEEF9-4AFF-937A-857A-2C27B845B755' AS uniqueidentifier) AS binary(16)) 
SET CONTEXT_INFO @sessionId
```

It it possible to put everything into one line statement?

Straightforward solution like following:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO CAST(CAST('A53BD5F9-4AFF-E211-857A-2C27D745B005' AS uniqueidentifier) AS binary(16))
```

This does not work, unfortunately. And I cannot get the reason of such behavior.

**EDIT:**

`sessionId` will be generated on-fly, so hard coding constant binary value won't work...

Comment: Can u try the below query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx

"SET CONTEXT_INFO does not accept expressions other than constants or variable names. To set the context information to the result of a function call, you must first include the result of the function call in a binary or varbinary variable. "

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @sessionId varbinary(128);
SET @sessionId = CAST(REPLICATE( 'A53BD5F9-4AFF-E211-857A-2C27D745B005', 128 ) AS varbinary(128) );
SET CONTEXT_INFO @sessionId ;
SELECT CONTEXT_INFO() AS MyContextInfo;
```

or Just add the following line under your query

```
    DECLARE @sessionId binary(16) = CAST(CAST('A53BEEF9-4AFF-937A-857A-2C27B845B755' AS uniqueidentifier) AS binary(16)) 
SET CONTEXT_INFO @sessionId
SELECT CONTEXT_INFO() AS MyContextInfo;
```

or if u could eliminate '-' you can do that

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0xA53BEEF94AFF937A857A2C27B845B755;
SELECT CONTEXT_INFO();
```

Comment: But this is even more lines, than in my code! I'm trying to find cleanest and shortest solution!

Answer (score 0):

Transact-SQL is a *very* simple language. In most modern languages, you'd expect to be able to supply an arbitrary expression in most locations where a simple value was valid - but that's not the case with T-SQL. So, if we look at the syntax diagram for [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx):

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO { binary_str | @binary_var }
```

You are allowed to supply exactly one of:

```
binary_str
```

> Is a **binary** constant, or a constant that is implicitly convertible to **binary**, to associate with the current session or connection.

```
@binary_var
```

> Is a **varbinary** or **binary** variable holding a context value to associate with the current session or connection.

And not any aribtrary expression that happens to *compute* a binary value.

---

Of course, without the `CAST`s, this would be a constant, so you could just write:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0xF9EE3BA5FF4A7A93857A2C27B845B755
```